# How to apply to all my activities a requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I want to hide the title to all my activities by doing

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

should I create an app class and put that in there? is there is example?
thank you

Comment: `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking, but for my app, I put this code inside all of my onCreate

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and it takes away the titlebar. You'll have to run the app to see the change since you aren't modifying the xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Application` because you have to use `getWindow().addFlags(..)` method from `Activity` class. You can use the suggested above options or create common parent `CommonActivity` and override `onCreate` there.